# Method overloading: function __call($method, $arg)

Tags: php

I have two classes: Address and Student. I need to code __call() function  so that the properties of the street, city and state can be retrieved and assigned using student instance.

This is the output I have (I coded __call() but it works only for the last line of output so far):

```
John Smith
50
, ,
The address has been updated:
50 second street, Palo Alto, CA
```

The third line of the output should be:

```
100 main street, Sunnyvale, CA
```

and that's where I got stack.

Here is my code. I will appreciate any help.

```
<?php
class Address {
private $street;
private $city;
private $state;

function __construct($s, $c, $st) {
    $this->street = $s;
    $this->city = $c;
    $this->state = $st;
}
function setCity($c) {
    $this->city = $c;
}
function getCity() {
    return $this->city;
}
function setState($s) {
    $this->state = $s;
}
function getState() {
    return $this->state;
}
function setStreet($s) {
    $this->street = $s;
}
function getStreet() {
    return $this->street;
}
}
class Student {
private $name;
private $age;
private $address;

function __construct($n, $a, Address $address) {
    $this->name = $n;
    $this->age = $a;
    $this->address = $address;
}

function getName() {
    return ucwords($this->name);
}

function getAge() {
    return $this->age;
}

function setName($n) {
    $this->name = $n;
}

function setAge($a) {
    $this->age = $a;
}

function __set($name, $value) {
    $set = "set".ucfirst($name);
    $this->$set($value);
}

function __get($name) {
    $get = "get".ucfirst($name);
    return $this->$get();
}

function __call($method, $arguments) {
    // Need more code 

    $mode = substr($method,0,3);
    $var = strtolower(substr($method,3));
    if ($mode =='get'){
        if (isset($this -> $var)){
            return $this ->$var;
        }
    } elseif ($mode == 'set') {
        $this ->$var = $arguments[0];
        }
    } 

}
$s = new Student('john smith', 50, '100 main street', 'Sunnyvale', 'CA');
echo $s->name;
echo "\n";
echo $s->age;
echo "\n";
echo $s->address->street . ", " . $s->address->city . ", " . $s->address->state;
echo "\n";
$s->street = "50 second street";
$s->city = "Palo Alto";
$s->state = "CA";
echo "The address has been updated:\n";
echo $s->street . ", " . $s->city . ", " . $s->state;


//print_r($s);

?>
```

Comment: aint worth it. Either add a get/setAddress() to Student and then call the getter/setter there or add proxy methods to the Student.

Answer (score 0):

The `street`, `city` and `state` must be `public`, or use the getters.

Change next:

```
$s = new Student('john smith', 50, '100 main street', 'Sunnyvale', 'CA');
```

for next:

```
$s = new Student('john smith', 50, new Address('100 main street', 'Sunnyvale', 'CA'));
```

And change next:

```
echo $s->address->street . ", " . $s->address->city . ", " . $s->address->state;
```

for next:

```
echo $s->address->getStreet() . ", " . $s->address->getCity() . ", " . $s->address->getState();
```

The Student constructor need a Address object, and the properties "street", "city" and "state" are "private", need to use "getters".

;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, but is there any way I should change something in function __call() instead of changing the general code? Sorry for asking, I'm new in PHP, so trying to learn :)

Comment: Yes, other way is change "private" for "public". Change next: { private $name; private $age; private $address; } for next: { public $name; public $age; public $address; }